# Error Partial xaml WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

[image]

I get this error, I try to copy my old project to another with modifing the name of namspace

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have another file with a partial definition of this same class that shares a different base class. Find this other partial definition and resolve.

Comment: I looke but there is no file have the same name