# NullException error WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

[image: NullException]

I get this error in App.cs, any help, I try to clean and build again but nothing.

Comment: This is the second question you have posted today which is simply a screenshot of Visual Studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121012/error-partial-xaml-wp7 please take a bit more effort in your question, describing your problem in words and including your exception / stacktrace within the question itself.

Comment: Ok maybe next error I will explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the line in question be as follows :-

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the `<PhoneApplicationService>` from `App.xaml`, it will be null. Either instance it, or make sure the `<PhoneApplicationService>` is present in your XAML.